# Remove a verticle in a tricky place

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image][image]I didn't know how to describe my problem in the title, so I'll try to do it here. Below I have a project. I needed to take a small piece from the middle of the object, and I couldn't get sculping to work, so I just used knife tool and excruded after I had created what I wanted.

Now, when I'm finally rendering, I'm getting unwanted things on the render result, caused by these extra verticles. Is it possible to remove them? I tried making the holes new objects, but that didn't really work.

Oh and, with 'verticle', I'm refering to the line that connects the hole into the rest of the object.[image]

http://www.filedropper.com/blend1 (a link to the blendfile)

Comment: can you show the render result?

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: thanks for update. Can you specify in the image which borders you want to delete? Is there a possibility to share the file?

Comment: I put the .blend into the main post now.

Just the two lines that are going out from the hole towards the body.

Oh and this is just a school project where I need to show rendered pictures, so if somebody has an idea how to fix the crappyness in rendering by changing texture mapping or whatnot, I'm fine with that, too.

Comment: where is the vertical its clean mesh http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=120329

Comment: I don't know if I'm using the right word, maybe what I'm referring to is 'edges'. The ones that are yellow in the new photo.

Comment: in my image there is nothing yellow edge

Comment: Can't have an ngon with a hole in it.  You can remove one edge, and have the other closer to the edge. [Similar to ngon here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42663/removing-doubles-on-imported-3dxml-ngon-mesh)

Comment: same issue as [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/22/2217)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top and bottom vertices are missaligned.

Select all the top vertices and tyoe these letters:

<kbd>s</kbd> ,  <kbd>z</kbd> ,  <kbd>0</kbd>  "Numpad zero". Not at the same time.

This will aling all these vertices in the Z axis.

Repeat these steps at the bottom vertices.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was it. I was wondering why it would have render issues cause of those verticles..