# How to remove unwanted edge between adjacent coplanar faces?

Tags: faces, edges

I have a wooden box with diagonal struts to make it sturdy (don't try to google, impossible to find):

[image: like this]

And it seems okay, but in edit mode it has meaningless edges appeared after tapping A -> Delete -> Limited Dissolve:

[image: look at edge bars]

How to get rid of these, they are increasing triangle amount with no point.

Comment: I don't think your topology is very convenient but anyway, have you tried to delete these edges with X > Dissolve Edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'meaningless' edges are not meaningless.

[image]

because, internally ..

- A face is bounded by a single unidirectional loop of edges .. so..
- An edge may not appear twice in the same loop

The red areas in first two examples above are not faces, as far as Blender is concerned. The last example qualifies to be 2 faces.

So in this case, Blender has held on to the minimum number of edges to preserve the faces around the frame of your crate. If you got rid one or both of those edges, (say, by deleting them ) the faces would have to go too.

Comment: Maybe worth  noting: Ngon geom like fig2 (2 outer edges with common geom as join)  is common when importing  shapefile data like [3dxml](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42663/removing-doubles-on-imported-3dxml-ngon-mesh).

Comment: Posting that comment made me realize it's   the _obvious_ answer to link posted.