# How do I convert .xmf file to an .obj file

Tags: import, file-format

How do I convert .xmf file to an .obj file with blender?

.xmf file is a 3D type of file. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to the site, kaila. You might want to take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and view the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help), especially the pages relating to asking and answering questions.

Comment: Appears to be quite a simple mesh format " 8 cal3d xml mesh file (.xmf) " from https://github.com/imvu/cal3d/blob/master/tools/converter/fileformats.txt and as such a simple importer could be coded like http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42300/import-3d-xml-in-blender-or-convert-it-with-another-tool/42590#42590

Answer (score 1):

The "short answer" to your question seems to be, "you can't, yet".

A more complete answer is that in the 3D software world, the ~.xmf file extension seems to be associated with a software package named [CAL3D](http://gna.org/projects/cal3d/), which is styled as a "character animation library". If an importer is being developed that would allow one to import this file format into Blender, it (or information about it) doesn't seem to have been released yet. It might be that the design philosophy of the developers of CAL3D is such that it might not be easily accomplished. If it is possible, when the add-on is released, one would download and install it, and use Blender to open the ~.xmf file and write the imported file to a file in ~.obj format.

Comment: dead link, see https://sourceforge.net/projects/cal3d/