# How to import XMF/XML files from IMVU into blender?

Tags: mesh

I was wondering if there was a way I could import XMF/XML files from IMVU in to 2.78 or 2.70? I've read two questions on the same topic but nothing provided worked for me.

Comment: Any advice would be helpful :)

Comment: Search is your friend, related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57048/how-do-i-convert-xmf-file-to-an-obj-file

Comment: I've searched every part of this site and others when it comes to importing XMF/XML files and nothing was helpful. Only a blender add-on to import City XML files...

Comment: XMF does sound rather propriety and probably lisenced, so I doubt that anyone has written a translation addon to import the files into Blender.

Comment: @DiamondBones007 https://create.imvu.com/knowledge-base/exporting-to-cal3d-from-blender/  and   https://www.katsbits.com/codex/imvu-export/    Sometimes it is easier to find blender related info  on, in this case,  IMVU forum posts, than vice versa.