# can anyone make me importer for this xml file type please?

Tags: export, import, file-format

so i need a simple importer and exporter for blender that can open these xml files.tried many different 3d xml file converters but non worked.i really appreciate it if anyone can make a one or suggest me a one that could do it for me.

here are some files of the ones i'm trying to convert:

https://ufile.io/8blhk

Comment: Welcome to [blender.se], please read the help and this [FAQ](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/30849). I downvoted for multiple reasons. (1) Question doesn't show any research. (2) Asker has no idea about the scope of the question. (3) The question mentions some failed methods but doesn't provide information on them. (4) The question doesn't provide details on the file format in question. (5) The question is invalid without some files from some leery third party site. | Look into bullet point 11 of the linked FAQ, ***Can someone do ____ for me?*** is not supported on this site.

Answer (score 1):

you should check this out: [Import 3D XML in Blender or convert it with another tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42300/import-3d-xml-in-blender-or-convert-it-with-another-tool)

I Don't know if this is exactly what you're wanting since the post doesn't have much explanation, but the op in that question had somewhat the same question as yours and someone posted a custom addon there, you should check it out.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/Skylumz/Sollumz
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYdWGfnmGe8

This is for gta peds and other xml imports for blender, just check out the github and the YT video will help you install it if you have any trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.