# How to use the XML file (which contains the tracking informations) produced by Faceware Analyzer with Blender,better if 2.8

Tags: animation, rigging, tracking

I'm playing with **FaceWare Analyzer**. I have imported a little video which contains the **facial (eyes,mouth,eyebrows) movements** of a guy,I have tracked them and I have exported the **XML file** which contains their **Landmark positions**.

[image: guy]

Now,I would like to use this XML file for making the retargeting with the poses. Faceware gives three tools for creating poses and generating animation,for Maya,for 3D studio max and for Motionbuilder,**BUT not for Blender**. So,the question is easy : which kind of tools,workflows can I use to do that in Blender (try to consider the new 2.8 build) ? As I said at this point I have only one XML file,which contains all the coordinates of the eyes,mouth and eyebrows movements of the guy on the video,that you can check [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eglwo9w-ul5sSB5YS1OMvWreDcSGsrpA).

This is how it looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Analyzer_Feature_File majorVersion="1" minorVersion="1">
  <meta>
    <video filePath="C:\Users\virtu\OneDrive\Documenti\Desktop\FaceWareTech\render00050364.mov" width="1272" height="720" frameRate="23,9760" videoStart="00:00:00:00" videoEnd="00:00:01:21" rangeStart="00:34:58:12" rangeEnd="00:35:00:09" />
  </meta>
  <frames>
    <frame value="0" valid="true" filePath="C:\Users\virtu\OneDrive\Documenti\Desktop\FaceWareTech\render00050364_fwt\video\render00050364_full\render00050364.00.jpg">
      <markup_groups>
        <markup_group name="Mouth">
          <landmarks>
            <landmark name="MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_VEE_RIGHT" label="MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_VEE_RIGHT" active="true">
              <texCoord u="0,4656" v="0,6235" />
              <position x="0" y="0" z="0" />
            </landmark>
            <landmark name="MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_VEE_RIGHT-MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_CORNER_RIGHT-0.33333" label="MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_VEE_RIGHT-MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_CORNER_RIGHT-0.33333" active="true">
              <texCoord u="0,4581" v="0,6221" />
              <position x="0" y="0" z="0" />
            </landmark>
            <landmark name="MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_VEE_RIGHT-MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_CORNER_RIGHT-0.66667" label="MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_VEE_RIGHT-MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_CORNER_RIGHT-0.66667" active="true">
              <texCoord u="0,4458" v="0,6208" />
              <position x="0" y="0" z="0" />
            </landmark>
            <landmark name="MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_CORNER_RIGHT" label="MOUTH_LIP_OUTER_CORNER_RIGHT" active="true">
              <texCoord u="0,4391" v="0,6185" />
              <position x="0" y="0" z="0" />
            </landmark>
```

Comment: Not unlike https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42300/import-3d-xml-in-blender-or-convert-it-with-another-tool  make an importer to read xml file and convert to blender.  Makes it a pretty broad (prob too broad) question for BSE. Would need research as to how a landmark correlates to a blender motion tracking marker... recommend adding the xml of a landmark to question.

Comment: what do u mean ? try to reload the page...

Comment: I wrote a script for your problem. Here is the result:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_KVs8sUCx8 Greetings OneOrk

Comment: did u solve the problem? Do you have the script?