# I have 3d mesh data of a mouse brain in XML format. How can I import it into blender?

Tags: mesh, import, volumetrics

I have 3d mesh data of a mouse brain in XML format. How can I import it into blender ?

[File Link](http://api.brain-map.org/grid_data/download/69816930)

[image]

Comment: Please add more info re the format. As an example See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42300/import-3d-xml-in-blender-or-convert-it-with-another-tool  The xml format is available online, an importer from a prior version of blender was linked.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=xml