# Animate/Create objects based on imported data

Tags: python, animation, scripting, import

Big picture: Animating data-packet exchange between network nodes. Each packet sent (from one node to another) is individually represented as an object moving along a path that connects the sender and receiver nodes.

Already finished: Network, nodes and paths along-which packets travel. Also, a couple of exemplary animations of data-packet exchange; one using particles and another where packets are represented as individual objects.

Incomplete/Missing part: While the network/nodes/paths are fixed in the scene, the number of packets transferred between nodes must be based on imported data that determines when a packet starts its animation (i.e. travel along its path) as well as how many packets start traveling. In other words, the missing part is a method to import data (XML file for example) that would affect both when and how many packets(objects) are created and traveling along a pre-existing path.

While not being quite experienced with XML and Python scripts within the context of Blender, Scripting-based feedback is also very much welcomed.

Alternatively, if the above described missing-part is simply outside the scope of Blender, then please feel free to suggest other solutions.

Note: NS-3 animation was sufficient, but based on the feedback received ... not quite presentation-level.

Thanks in advance for your feedback :)

Comment: I believe this is within the scope of Blender, though I don’t immediately know how to do it. As always, see docs.blender.org for information on the API and blender itself if you need a reference.

Comment: Example of importing an XML format into blendr https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42300/import-3d-xml-in-blender-or-convert-it-with-another-tool